# Storm-YARN : Application container fails to launch

Tags: hadoop, apache-storm, hadoop-yarn

I am running a storm (trident) topology that reads avro from kafka & writes the records in hbase.
The topology is running as expected in Localcluster mode, but while using Stormsubmitter I'm facing below issues.

- In Distributed Hadoop mode I'm getting the below error [1] while launching the YARN application.
- In Hadoop (local mode, with 1 box only) Yarn is spawnning the nimbus server and storm-ui. But there are no supervisor(s) running to run the spout/bolts in the topology. I guess the reason might be insufficient memory (4G to run the topology + hbase, hdfs, kafka, zookeeper etc...).

Can you help me out in understanding the reason of this container failure? There are no errors/info present in application logs.

[1] YARN container fails to launch with below error on running.
`storm-yarn launch /homext/storm-yarn.yml --queue default -appname storm-yarn-demo --stormZip /tmp/storm-0.9.zip`

```
Application application_1415038356032_0304 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1415038356032_0304_000002 exited with exitCode: 127 due to: Exception from container-launch: org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException:
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException:
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:505)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:418)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:650)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:195)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:283)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:79)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 127
.Failing this attempt.. Failing the application.
```

Answer (score 0):

This log is insufficient to diagnose. All it says is that the container failed to launch. You should look into the container output. Check the `${yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs}` on the nodes, there will be an application folder (application_1415038356032_0304) and in there there will be a container folder for each attempt (...1415038356032_0304_000002) containing the stderr, stdout and syslog of this attempt. Read those and you'll likely identify the problem.

If these don't exist, look in `${yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs}` you'll find the container launch script (I thinks is called `container-launch.sh`) for this app/container attempt. In it will be the actual command to launch the container. Try to run that from the shell prompt and see what you get.

Comment: I did check both log-dirs & local-dirs there isn't any log file or container launch script present.

Comment: I've checked.
  ll -R ${yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs}
  total 0
&
  ll -R ${yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs}
  this has
  filecache/20/storm-0.9.zip/storm-0.9.0-wip21: has storm.zip files contents
  /usercache/user/appcache: EMPTY
  usercache/ciuser/filecache: EMPTY
  usercache_DEL_1408* EMPTY

Comment: did you look on all nodes?

Comment: You also need to look shortly after the failure, the NM will clean up these files eventually (how soon depends on how is configured).

Comment: If you still cannot find the info, try enabling `debug` log for `org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor` in the log4j config (on the node) and retry the attempt.

Answer (score 0):

If it fails at an early stage then the logs can be found in HDFS under:

```
/tmp/logs/<user>/logs/
```

This should give enough information to diagnose the problem.

In my case I found a log file:

```
/tmp/logs/hdfs/logs/application_1426618997634_0004/vagrant-cdh-node4_8041
```

With some errors like:

```
/bin/bash: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

And fixing the JAVA_HOME environment variable did the trick.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before any further participating.

Comment: You said, that you have the same problem. You did not provide any solution for it. I know, that you cannot comment yet, but this kind of information should go to comments - not to answers.

Comment: His real problem was not being able to find the logs that would diagnose his problem, this answers that. I wasn't just saying yeah me too. I posted this because if it had been here I wouldn't have had to spend an hour looking for the logs for when storm yarn fails at an early stage.